# SQL replies with multiple replies

Tags: sql

I do apologize and I am willing to edit the name of this, didn't know the best way to title this.

I have a table `table_1` (1 column) with unique values (Combo Names) that I am trying to pass as a condition to another table `table_2` that has 2 sets of UIDs (one is the combo UID and the other is component UID, both are in table 3 as items) that needs to pull from a third table `table_3` with the names of `table_1` and UIDs of `table_2`.

I know that is really complicated! Or at least it is for me...

My query returns duplicate information because I think I am passing the same information back on to itself...

My SQL looks like this:

```
Select i.item_id as Combo_kit_id, c.item_id as Component_item_id
from table_3 i 
inner join table_1 t on i.item_id = t.item_id 
inner join table_2 a on i.item_uid = a.assembly_uid
inner join table_3 c on a.component_uid = c.item_uid
```

table_1:

```
| item_ID |
----------
|  CA123  |
|  CA124  |
|  CA125  |
|  CA126  |
|  CA127  |
|  CA128  |
|  CA129  |
---------
```

table_2:

```
| assembly_UID | component_UID |
--------------------------------
|   1234       |      2234     |
|   1234       |      2235     |
|   1236       |      2236     |
|   1236       |      2237     |
|   1239       |      2238     |
|   1239       |      2239     |
|   1243       |      2242     |
|   1243       |      2288     |
--------------------------------
```

table_3:

```
| item_ID |   item_UID  |
-------------------------
| CA123   |    1234     |
| CA124   |    1236     |
| CA125   |    1239     |
| CA126   |    1243     |
| CA127   |    2234     |
| CA128   |    2235     |
| CA129   |    2236     |
| CA130   |    2237     |
| CA131   |    2238     |
| CA132   |    2239     |
| CA133   |    2242     |
| CA134   |    2288     |
-------------------------
```

My result is:

```
| Combo_kit_id | Component_item_id |
-----------------------------------
|  CA123      |   CA127      |
|  CA123      |   CA127      |
|  CA123      |   CA128      |
|  CA123      |   CA128      |
|  CA124      |   CA129      |
|  CA124      |   CA129      |
|  CA124      |   CA130      |
|  CA124      |   CA130      |
|  CA125      |   CA131      |
|  CA125      |   CA131      |
|  CA125      |   CA132      |
|  CA125      |   CA132      |
------------------------------
```

Is there a way not to get the added duplicates?

Comment: Please fix `JOIN table_2` to use existing field names.

Comment: great catch! Sorry

Comment: Your query references `c.item_uid` where `c` is an alias for `table_1`.  The sample data you've shown doesn't include this column.

Comment: Now, How do I title this thing?

Comment: @DaveCosta Typo... I'll edit it.. It is supposed join table_3 again...

Comment: OK .. with the data and query you have now, I don't see how you are getting the duplicates in the first place.  Example: CA123 in table1 matches 1 row in table3; 1234 in table3 matches 2 rows in table2; 2234 and 2235 in table2 each match 1 row in table3.  So you should have a total of 2 rows for CA123 in your result.

Comment: @DaveCosta EXACTLY!!!!!! I am overlooking something, I know it! I'm sorry TheImpaler, I just don't see why I would need to use 'Distinct'

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2012 and SQL Studio

Comment: Here is a screenshot via Dropbox of the results... The actual code..[Dropbox Picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uncpbm5ys20ca7d/Duplicates.bmp?dl=0)

Comment: Well... your actual code has a LIKE condition in it, that kind of changes things

Comment: If you're going to post sample code, make sure it's actually producing the result you show

Comment: I'm not really sure how it changes anything... Yes the like is different but should still have the same concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just use `distinct`?

```
Select distinct i.item_id as Combo_kit_id, c.item_id as Component_item_id
from table_3 i 
inner join table_1 t on i.item_id = t.item_id 
inner join table_2 a on i.item_uid = a.item_uid
inner join table_1 c on a.component_uid = c.item_uid
```

Comment: I had thought about that... but I feel there may be multiple components assigned to different combo numbers and multiple combo numbers having the same components...

Comment: The `distinct` keyword works on the full row, not on every column. Therefore it removes duplicate **rows**. Is this what you need, or something different?

Comment: Weird! I passed it off at first thinking that it couldn't work due to the idea that this was a many to many relationship and I didn't want to miss a piece. But it works! Thank you! correct answer and it says quite a bit that It took far longer for me to ask the question than it was for you to answer it!